# How to use a FireDAC TFDConnection to iterate through tables, fields and field definitions

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

I am teaching myself to use SQLite and FireDAC together in Delphi. I am not very experienced with the latest incarnations of databases and tools so after writing a very simple application to display a single table from an SQLite file, I decided that I would put together a simple viewer 'frame' that would help me learn and maybe give me (eventually) a debugging tool to put in my Application for engineering use.

So, I've used a simple TTreeView and I wish to populate it with a hierarchy of 'databases' (catalogues?), 'tables', 'field names' and 'field types'. So far it has been remarkably easy to list the catalogues, tables and fields (using TFDConnection.Getxxxxx) but I cant see how to go deeper to get field definitions.  Is this possible to do from a TFDConnection? Or do I need to open a temporary query?

My existing code is shown below and my 'field types' would be a further nested loop when shown as '// xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

  procedure DatabaseToTreeView( AConnection : TFDConnection; ATreeView : TTreeView );

    procedure ProcessConnection;

      procedure ProcessCatalogueName( const ACatalogueName : string; ARoot : TTreeNode );

        procedure ProcessTableName( const ATableName : string; ARoot : TTreeNode );
        var
          List : TStrings;
          {Node : TTreeNode;}
          I    : integer;
        begin
          List := TStringList.Create;
          try
            AConnection.GetFieldNames( ACatalogueName, '', ATableName, '', List );
            for I := 0 to List.Count-1 do
              begin
              {Node := }ATreeView.Items.AddChild( ARoot, List[I] );
              // xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
              end;
          finally
            List.Free;
          end;
        end;

      var
        List : TStrings;
        Node : TTreeNode;
        I    : integer;
      begin
        List := TStringList.Create;
        try
          AConnection.GetTableNames( ACatalogueName, '', '', List );
          for I := 0 to List.Count-1 do
            begin
            Node := ATreeView.Items.AddChild( ARoot, List[I] );
            ProcessTableName( List[I], Node );
            end;
        finally
          List.Free;
        end;
      end;


    var
      List : TStrings;
      Node : TTreeNode;
      I    : integer;
    begin
        List := TStringList.Create;
        try
          AConnection.GetCatalogNames( '', List );

          if List.Count = 0 then
            ProcessCatalogueName( '', nil )
           else
            for I := 0 to List.Count-1 do
              begin
              Node := ATreeView.Items.AddChild( nil, List[I] );
              ProcessCatalogueName( List[I], Node );
              end;
        finally
          List.Free;
        end;
    end;


  begin
    ATreeView.Items.Clear;
    ATreeView.Items.BeginUpdate;
    try
      ProcessConnection;
    finally
      ATreeView.Items.EndUpdate;
    end;
  end;

begin
  FDConnection1.Open;
  FDQuery1.Active := true;

  DatabaseToTreeView( FDConnection1, TreeView1 );

end;
```

Many thanks, Brian.

Comment: You can use the [`TADMetaInfoQuery`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/firedac/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=uADCompClient_TADMetaInfoQuery.html) class and query the `mkTableFields` type of [`MetaInfoKind`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/firedac/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=uADCompClient_TADMetaInfoQuery_MetaInfoKind.html). That will return you `COLUMN_DATATYPE` and `COLUMN_TYPENAME` (see the [`Metadata Structure`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/firedac/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=Metadata_Structure.html) chapter).

Comment: @TLama: This worked for me and would seem to be the 'correct' way, thanks. After following your link to the FD documentation I stumbled on a perfect example project in "C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\Samples\Delphi\Database\FireDAC\Samples\Comp Layer\TFDMetaInfoQuery" which does pretty much everything. Why oh why cant we get a detailed list of Delphi examples and what they do!!

Comment: You're welcome! Yup, it seems to be the best fitting component for your task. And yes, it would be nice to have a list of example descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to instantiate a TFDTable, connect it to AConnection and call FieldDefs.Update. This won't fetch any data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this only works if I replace Table.FieldDefs.Update with Table.Active := True. I am only doing Table.Connection=xxx and Table.TableName := ATableName though, is there another field I should initialise?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**TFDMetaInfoQuery**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDMetaInfoQuery) component. It is unified for getting metadata information, so it's usable with any kind of supported DBMS. It populates [**metadata resultsets**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Metadata_Structure_(FireDAC)) by the requested [**MetaInfoKind**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDMetaInfoQuery.MetaInfoKind) and given DBMS object description.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using a temporary query with a false condition to get table schema without any data (such as  "select * from tablename where 1=0" - I assume that is what you meant), depending on your database, you could also use a query to get table information. Like;

For MySQL:

```
show columns from  tablename;
```

For SQLite:

```
PRAGMA table_info(tablename)
```

For MS SQL Server:

```
select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'tablename';
```

I believe PostgreSQL also has such a function, however I dont have a pgsql installation handy at this time.